# How can I make `find` find files in reverse chronological order?

Tags: bash, unix, find

I want to find files in subdirectories sorted by timestamp (of creation), with most recent first.

I have looked at the man page but it seems to only seems to let you filter by timestamp rather than sort by timestamp.

What options can I pass to `find` to accomplish this? 
Alternately, how can I combine it with another tool, like `sort` to sort by timestamp?

Comment: You can't make `find` do anything in a particular sorted order, beyond choosing between a depth-first search and a breadth-first search.

Comment: @merlin2011, please review your selection of answers here -- the presently-selected answer is buggy (will generate outputs which are not actually correctly sorted) when there are more files found by `find` than can be passed to a single instance of `ls`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thanks for the note! I've updated the accepted answers.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

While Paul's solution is generally OK, it involves more I/O than simply:

```
find bin/ -type f -printf '%Ts\t%p\n' | sort -nr | cut -f2
```

Comment: What if `find` returns millions of files? Isn't sort going to sort all of them as one very long list? Is it still going to be efficient? (Instead of sorting each directory independently.)

Comment: Doesn't work with funny characters in file names, like newlines

Comment: This deserves only a comment on user7385's answer, but I don't have the reputation to do that. `find bin/ -type f -printf '%Ts\t%p\0' | sort -nrz | cut -f2 -z | xargs -0 ls` New versions of `cut` have the -z option, so filenames with newlines would work.

Comment: The amount of I/O isn't even the primary reason to prefer this answer -- *correctness* is a much more critical distinction. The `xargs -0 ls -t` approach won't work correctly when there are so many files that `xargs` needs to start `ls` more than once, but this approach will continue to function.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, "sorting them all as one very long list" is the only way to sort them that actually returns a correct result. Moreover, the other/accepted answer *doesn't* "sort each directory independently" either (if one wanted to sort only a single directory without recursing, one might use `-maxdepth 1` on the `find`).